# Zend Framework Can't determine mime type of image upload

Tags: zend-framework

Hi all I'm trying to upload a image when creating a item in my app, however the action fails returning the following error: **The mimetype of file 'mytestimage.jpg' could not be detected**.
I've tried adding a Mime Type validator but the error persists, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong in the code below.

```
// Image uploads
$images = new Zend_Form_Element_File('images');
$images->setMultiFile(2)
       ->addValidator('IsImage')
       ->addValidator('Size',false,'5242880')
       ->addValidator('Extension',false,'jpg,png,gif')
       ->addValidator('ImageSize',false,array(
                 'minwidth' => 250,
                 'minheight'=>250,
                 'maxwidth'=>500,
                 'maxheight'=>500
                 ))
       ->setValueDisabled(true);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Graham

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Zend_Frameworks tries to determine the mimetype in two ways:

- First it tries to use the PECL FILEINFO-Extension (which is not installed on every server)
- if the extension is not istalled it tries to use `mime_content_type` (a php function). This function however is deprecated as of php version 5.3

So in this case I guess your hoster is using php version 5.3 and has not installed the PECL FILEINFO-Extension. Same goes unfortunately for my hoster :(

Here are more details of the two ways in the php-manual:

- http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php
- http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

By the way. You can see the code ZF uses in the file "Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http.php" (lines 1281-1318: methodname is `_detectMimeType`

Comment: Sorry I meant to say this also happens on my localhost (win7 machine) I will look at my local php file (5.3.5). I will look at loading this extension in my php config file.

Comment: loading the extension in my local php file worked I'll review this with my hoster and see what php version they are using.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. Hope your hoster will install it for you. Cheers :)